# how to sort recursive query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql query to find all replies from orig comment:

```
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
        SELECT blog_comments_comment.*, 0 AS relative_depth
        FROM blog_comments_comment
        WHERE id in %s

        UNION ALL

        SELECT blog_comments_comment.*, children.relative_depth + 1
        FROM blog_comments_comment,children
        WHERE blog_comments_comment.reply_to_id = children.id
    )
    SELECT id,post_id, name,body, reply_to_id, relative_depth
    FROM children
    ORDER BY children;
```

How can I sort it to have it like this?

```
-main comment
---reply to main comment
------reply to reply
----------etc
---2nd reply to main comment
------reply to 2nd reply
----------etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain the path and sort:

```
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
        SELECT bcc.*, 0 AS relative_depth,
               array[bcc.id] as path
        FROM blog_comments_comment bcc
        WHERE id in %s    
        UNION ALL    
        SELECT bcc.*, c.relative_depth + 1,
               path || c.id
        FROM children c JOIN
             blog_comments_comment bcc
             ON bcc.reply_to_id = bcc.id
    )
SELECT id,post_id, name,body, reply_to_id, relative_depth
FROM children
ORDER BY path;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b80ad692932460f70421c5238c93766) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @MilezNoles . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?  It should be sorting by the path, which should be depth first.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but it still gives not quite right result

Comment: @MilezNoles . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: "path || bcc.id" this change to your answer solves my problem. Huge thanks to you!